# How to create nested object in MongoDB schema, nested object and array MEAN stack

Tags: json, mongodb, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to design a nested MongoDB schema.

Currently, I have this schema and it's working:

```
var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rate: number
    date: Date
})
```

But I wanna expend it to get:

```
var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    currency: {
        mxn: Number,
        php: Number,
    },
    source: [String],
    deliveryMethod: [String],
    date: Date
})
```

For source, I want to get an array of inputs ex. ["bank", "debit card", "agent"]
and almost samething for deliverymethod.

But either my input is wrong or my schema, because the value for source saves as one long string, not a separated value.

Also, I think the way I designed the currency to have more currency rate is correct but I don't know how my input json should suppose to be.

I tried it in postman:

```
{
    "name": "google",
    "currency": {
        "mxn": 20,
        "php": 30
    }
}
```

and this is the result i got:

```
{
"status": 201,
"data": {
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "google",
    "date": "2017-12-06T22:38:45.896Z",
    "_id": "5a2871752e3b7343dc388549",
    "deliveryMethod": [
        null
    ],
    "source": [
        null
    ]
},
"message": "Succesfully Created  Company"
}
```

1- if my currency nested schema is correct how should be my post json file be?

2- how can I get source and deliveryMethod as an array of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON in the request body should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "google",
    "currency": {
        "mxn": 20,
        "php": 30
    },
    "source": ["source1", "source 2", "source 3"],
    "deliveryMethod": ["delMetd 1", "delMetd 2", "delMetd 3"],
    "date": "2015-11-27T23:00:00Z"
}
```

I copy/pasted your code and tried with Postman. The response I got back was:

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "google",
    "date": "2015-11-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "_id": "5a2915295c5f714f7cb25d90",
    "deliveryMethod": [
        "delMetd 1",
        "delMetd 2",
        "delMetd 3"
    ],
    "source": [
        "source1",
        "source 2",
        "source 3"
    ],
    "currency": {
        "mxn": 20,
        "php": 30
    }
}
```

If I connect to the database with the mongo shell and run `db.companies.find().pretty()` I get this result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a2915295c5f714f7cb25d90"),
        "name" : "google",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-11-27T23:00:00Z"),
        "deliveryMethod" : [
                "delMetd 1",
                "delMetd 2",
                "delMetd 3"
        ],
        "source" : [
                "source1",
                "source 2",
                "source 3"
        ],
        "currency" : {
                "mxn" : 20,
                "php" : 30
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Your schema is fine. You can try dropping the collection (`db.companies.drop()`) if you can't get it to work. Start with a fresh one if you don't have any important data in it.

Comment: Thanks, @MikaS, but what was your body of your input in JSON file? I think the structure of the data I'm sending in postman is wrong. Can you share it, please?

Comment: @Milad The body is exactly like I posted. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/tWhLwx0.png) screenshot from Postman.

Comment: I figure it out. I was sending a correct raw JSON file but, the way I defined it in the back-end was wrong.